# iPad Splitview in Portrait Mastertable as default swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, splitview

I'm playing around with Master-Detail out of the box Template. I got it to run and even the Buttons are there on iPhone-Plus. Now I've some issues.

On the iPad and portrait mode the App always starts in **DetailView**, I found a workaround for at least getting an **Back Button** but I want to start in portrait mode with the **MasterView** as TableView(like on iPhone or at least whit master and Detail). When I hit the **Back** button the table slides in. (in Landscape is everything fine due to the split view)

**Question:**

- How to start in MasterTableview when iPad is in portrait mode (like on iPhone incl. 6+)?
- How to get rid of the tableview when row is selected and the "detail view" should appear. (only "detail view" should be visible)?
- or at least how to approach the same behavior like the "setting" on iPad

Comment: I found a solution for Question No.3

Comment: I found a solution for Question No.3: The out of the box template doesn't implement the UISplitviewControllerDelegate in DetailViewController , so you have to add it. Further more add in ViewDidLoad: if let splitVCExists = self.splitViewController{
        splitVCExists.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
    } That I got from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790804/split-view-in-portrait-mode?lq=1

Comment: Have you found the solution for No.1? I'm facing that issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did found a second approach:(for Part 3)
After adding the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` to the DetailViewController put in the `viewDidLoad` this `self.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryOverlay`. That will show both, but the DetailView is NOT adjusted to fit on the right side.
If you want to show both Master and Detail (DetailView fit to the right) `self.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible`

```
self.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryOverlay // for overlay Detail will be  hidden half
self.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible  // detail will fit into right
```