# Changing to a different view when rotating a Split View Controller in iPad (iOS6)

Tags: ios, ios6, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller, screen-rotation

I've got a SplitView Controller for iPad, which should display a Calculator which I made in portrait mode, and a Graph calculator when rotated into landscape mode.

This is what my storyboard looks like currently, am I doing it wrong?

[image]

I'm still new to the whole SplitView Controller concept in iOS, so I ain't sure how this whole thing works.

Currently, only the highlighted view gets displayed in both landscape and portrait mode, but I only want to display it in landscape mode, and display the calculator in portrait mode, as well as remove the option to display the `Master` button from portrait mode, but display it in landscape mode i.e. don't display the `Master Table` in landscape mode, only when the button is pressed.

Comment: Why are you using a split view?

Comment: Part of the requirement, as I need to be able to enter Graph plots in the table (x and y points), hence the necessary split view

Answer (score 0):

Apple's SplitView Controller doesn't allow hiding the master view in landscape mode, but you could use a custom class, like [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11109006/2175611)

For the screen-rotation part, just do a modal segue when the orientation changes.

This will notify you when the orientation changes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(changeOrientation:)  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Then for the function

```
- (void) changeOrientation : (UIDeviceOrientation) orientation {
    if(!UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(orientation))
        return;
    if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) { // Or UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUENAME" sender:self];
    }
}
```

More about segues: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13980519/2175611)