# Legally Retaining Split View in Portrait Mode

Tags: ipad

Two similar questions have been asked here before:

[Split view in portrait mode!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790804/split-view-in-portrait-mode)

[Forcing an iPad app to show splitView even in Portrait orientation(Like the Settings iPad app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624234/forcing-an-ipad-app-to-show-splitview-even-in-portrait-orientationlike-the-sett)

Both questions were largely answered with "not officially supported - roll your own or use a third-party custom controller"

However, I'm digging through WWDC 2011 Apple Developer videos (Session 102, specifically), and about 30 minutes in the presenter declares that this feature now *is* supported in iOS 5.  The problem is that I don't know how to implement it.  Here's the code from the slide:

```
@protocol UISplitViewControllerDelegate
...
// Returns YES if a view controller should be hidden by
// the split view controller in a given orientation.
// (This method is only called on the leftmost view controller
// and only discriminates portrait from landscape.)
- (BOOL)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc
    shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
        inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;
@end
```

So - what do I do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read through a bunch of stuff and actually found the way to do it correctly now. Go to your `detailViewController`. Your `detailViewController` should have `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`. And simply just drop this code in:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
    return NO;
}
```

This will make all the view stay in place. Let me know, if it works for you.